# How to expose local machine running Kubernetes and Istio ingress

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, istio, docker-for-mac

I have a machine on a local network, that I have exposed to the Internet via port forwarding in the router.

Now how can I expose the serving machine running Kubernetes on docker for mac?

using minikube you can do:

```
minikube tunnel
```

But how to do it on mac for mac/desktop?

Normally the LoadBalancer is created for you if you use a cloud provider.

Comment: Yes, you just need to add the port you want it to listen on and the port you are forwarding it to in the pod: `kubectl port-forward pod/pod-name local_port:pod_port`, I think. Something along those lines. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for using Istio(ingress gateway) not only for pods.

Answer (score 1):

The command suggested by @Marko is almost correct.

The command:

```
➜  ~ kubectl port-forward pod/pod-name local_port:pod_port
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 80
```

opens a port but only locally (on loopback interface/localhost). To make it accessible from the outside you need to pass `--address=0.0.0.0. So the complete command is:

```
➜  ~ kubectl port-forward pod/pod-name local_port:pod_port --address=0.0.0.0
Forwarding from 0.0.0.0:local_port -> pod_port
```

Comment: Thanks for updating the command from my comment. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for using Istio(ingress gateway) not only for pods.

Comment: Just expose the istio ingress gateway pod/service. because Istio gateway IS a pod